# Google Map API em aplicação desktop

Tags: google-maps, aplicação-desktop

Estou com um projeto no qual preciso adicionar as funções do google map em um aplicativo desktop.
Minha ideia é fazer isso através de um componente(Widget) WebView. Porém não sei absolutamente nada de como funciona a API google map.

Preciso de um ponto de partida.

Comment: Seria interessante você limitar sua necessidade, do jeito que está é muito amplo. Por exemplo, será um [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) do JavaFX? Dependendo da abordagem você pode usar API JS, dependendo a HTTP =D

Comment: Certo!
A aplicação é desenvolvida em c++/qt

Comment: E quais *features* você precisa usar? Dependendo existe algo pronto e melhor para plotar, então você só usaria apenas coisas como *geocoding*, *places*, etc. Em C++ não consigo postar nada por agora, mas dependendo tento bolar um exemplo

Comment: Não conheço muito, como se chamam as features do google map. Mas basicamente o que vou precisar é a função de calculo de rotas, places e geocoding.
O software tem que ter a marcação (places?) da localização dos clientes da empresa. O celular dos representantes vai se comunicar com a aplicação mandando de tempos em tempos sua localização, o software principal poderá acompanhar a rota, sabendo quanto do trajeto já foi percorrido, quanto tempo custará para chegar ao destino etc.
A comunicação entre o celular dos representantes e a aplicação ainda não foi decidido, pode ser por sms ou webservice.